# Why OnActivtiyResult not called in fragment? Xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I set StartActivityForResult, but OnActivtiyResult is not called in fragment that implements Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.
Here is the code:

```
public class AccountProfileFragment : SupportFragment
{
...
btn_edit_photo = frgView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.edit_image);
btn_edit_photo.SetOnClickListener(this);
...
}
 public void OnClick(View v)
 {
   if(v.id = Resource.Id.edit_image)
   {
    ChoosePhoto();
   }
  }

 public void ChoosePhoto()
  {
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.SetType("image/*");
   intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
   StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

  }

public virtual void OnActivtiyResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, -1, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST &&
            data != null && data.Data != null)
        {
            filePath = data.Data;

            try {...} catch (IOException e) {...}
        }
    }
```

How you see, I tried put **virtual** before OnActivtiyResult and in base.OnActivityResult I pass just **-1** as the second parameter. And still it doesn't work. Could you give any idea?

Comment: You may remove `base.OnActivityResult` call, it should work

Comment: guisantogui , I commented base.OnActivityResult , it didn't help. I made public override void OnActivtiyResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) then it give error "not found method to override" and did int resultCode instead Result resultCode according to answers previous similar question. But nothing worked for me